# How to translate odoo 10 password reset page

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I have to translate the password reset page i.e. `http://localhost:8069/web/reset_password?token=<token>` to the language of URL for whom I am trying to reset the password.

I can see these the labels in translated terms but they are not getting translated even if the language of the user is not English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation of password reset page depends upon the default language of the browser. It will automatically be translated once the language is getting changed. But I am not able to find a way to manually set it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found solution.

1. Export Translation:

   1. Choose language, in my case Spanish.
   2. File format : PO
   3. Modules to export (ex: sales, stock, invoicing etc).
   4. Click on the Export button and download ar_SY.po file

2.Change `msgstr` in *.po file.

3. Put that file in `mymodule/i18/ar_SY.po.
4. Upgrade the module.

Comment: I have tried that, As I have written in my question, I can see the terms in translated terms and PO files as well but it is not getting reflected at password reset page.